# Emberjs Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'get'

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to use a model to create a dynamic route that will show the date in the URL but I'm getting a typedef error and I can't see which get it's talking about and why it's giving me the error.
Is it my model or my route that is giving me the error. How do I avoid this from happening when when I try creating dynamic routes? What's a good source or book that can show me the ends and out of Ember?

```
    var App = Ember.Application.create({
        LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
    });

    App.Router.map(function(year, month, date) {
        this.resource('calendar');
        this.resource('about'); 
        this.resource('utcDate', {path: ':utcDate'});
    });

    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        redirect: function(){
            this.transitionTo('calendar');
        }
    });

    App.CalendarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function(){
            return App.CalendarData.create();
        },
        model: function(params, transition){
            return {utcDate: params.utcDate}
        },
        serializer: function(model){
            return {utcDate: model.get('utcDate')};
        },
        serializer: function(model){
            return {month: model.get('Today')};
        }
    });

    // calendar controller
    App.CalendarController = Ember.Controller.extend({

//something here seems to be throwing an error that I can't troubleshoot       
      utcDate: function() {
        return this.get("model").get("utcDate");
      }.property("model"),

      days: function() {
        return this.get("model").get("days");
      }.property("model"),

      date: function() {
        return this.get("model").get("date");
      }.property("model"),

      month: function(){
        return this.get('model').get('month');
      }.property('model'),

      dow: function(){
        return this.get('model').get('dow');
      }.property('model'),

      year: function(){
        return this.get('model').get('year');
      }.property('model')
    });

    // calendar data
    App.CalendarData = Ember.Object.extend({
        today: new Date(),

        utcDate: function(){
          return this.get('today').getMonth()+1 + '/'+ this.get('today').getDate()+'/'+this.get('today').getFullYear();
        }.property('today'),

        date: function(){
          return this.get("today").getDate();
        }.property('today'),

        days: function(){
          var Mdays = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
          var Ndays =  Mdays[this.get('today').getMonth()];
          var days = [];
          var cDays = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            days[i] = [];
              for (j = 0; j <=6; j++) {
                if (cDays <= Ndays){
                  days[i][j] = cDays++;
                } else{
                  days[i][j] = " "
                }
              }
          }
          return days;
        }.property('today'),

        month: function(){
          var MonthA = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",  "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
          var month = MonthA [this.get('today').getMonth()];
          return month;
        }.property('today'),

        dow: function(){
          var Weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday",  "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
          var dow= Weekday[this.get('today').getDay()];
          return dow;
        }.property('today'),

        year: function(){
          return this.get('today').getFullYear();
        }.property('today')
    });
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yicuh/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the `model` hook and `serialize` hook defined multiple times.

```
App.CalendarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.CalendarData.create();
    },
    model: function(params, transition){
        return {utcDate: params.utcDate}
    },
    serializer: function(model){
        return {utcDate: model.get('utcDate')};
    },
    serializer: function(model){
        return {month: model.get('Today')};
    }
});
```

I guessed I chose one of each, but additionally if an object isn't an ember object you'll need to use `Ember.get(object, property)` instead of `object.get(property)`.

```
App.CalendarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.CalendarData.create();
    },
    serializer: function(model){
        return {utcDate: Em.get(model,'utcDate')};
    },
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wemoc/1/edit

Comment: Beautiful!
I'm trying to make the utcDate the default route. I seem to have it defined but Ember disagrees with me.
Ahh it IS working but as utcDate and not in the format that the utcdate is in. 
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qihuz/1/